# Software serial and port expanders

Tags: serial, esp32

On my ESP32 project I've run out of pins and have incorporated using a MCP23017 port expander.  I need to run multiple slow serial connections (9600 baud) thru the port expander.  Are there any software serial libraries available that would work over a port expander?

Comment: No. Even 9600 baud would be beyond the capabilities of bit-banging through a port expander. Reconsider your topology. What are you trying to achieve that needs you to use multiple UARTs like that?

Comment: I have several DHT22's that I want to interface with.  One option is to use a mux on the tx/rx pins such as a 74HC4052.

Comment: using a one-way serial connection might half your pins, if you weren't aware that was possible...